# Changes push notification of apple

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, apple-push-notifications, ionic4

I got the following message from apple.

"The HTTP / 2-based Apple Push Notification Service Provider (APN) API lets you take advantage of great features like authentication with a JSON web token, improved error messages, and per-notification feedback. If you are still sending push notifications with the legacy binary protocol, make sure to update to the APN provider's API as soon as possible. APNs will no longer support the legacy binary protocol after March 31, 2021."

I have to investigate if it is going to impact the project.
Currently notifications are handled by a plugin called: phonegap-push-notification, with a forked havesoruce.
But I can't find or don't see where in the plugin it uses what apple wants to modify. I don't know if the changes will impact, I don't know if when updating the plugin, the apple changes will be made in the system.
How do I know if my app uses legacy binary protocol, where do I see that?

APP:use ionic 3, AngularJs.

Comment: Yes, indeedy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911